# How to Provide Padding to a div so that if elemwnt comes to second line the padding is should work on that also

Tags: html, css, padding

I have 2 divs on which I am using flex property, where 1st div is used as a label and the second one is used as its data because of the text length 2nd div data it's going on the second line and when I am giving padding property it doesn't have any effect of padding property.

Below is the image for better understanding of my problem.[image]

Comment: can you post your html and css code

Comment: please try to provide code or working demo of what you tried or doing so we can help you to sort it out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please follow this